# Spring taglib not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When i include spring taglib in my jsp page, its showing the whole jsp code at my localhost.Am unable to find what is wrong in it.
I have given jstl dependency in maven pom.xml file.

Please suggest me solutions to this.

```
addEmployee.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Employee</h1>
    <form:form commandName="employee">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Firstname:</td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lastname:</td>
            <td><form:input path="lastname"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Date of Birth:</td>
            <td><form:input path="dob" type="date"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Employee">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources location="assets" mapping="/assets/**"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.employee.controller"/>

     <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EmployeeManagement</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EmployeeManagement</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EmployeeManagement</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EmployeeManagement</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EmployeeManagement</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EmployeeManagement</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springmvctest.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>FitnessTrackerTest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

<!--   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency> -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

employee.controller

```
package com.employee.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.employee.model.Employee;
import com.employee.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/addEmployee",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addEmployee(Model model){
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee",employee);
        return "addEmployee";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addEmployee",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, BindingResult result){

        if(result.hasErrors()){

            return "addEmployee";
        }
        else{

            employeeService.save(employee);
        }
        return "redirect:index.jsp";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSP is not the problem. Show us your Servlet configuration and your MVC setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have added the servlet-config.xml. I am following MVC standard, where my jsp files is  at WebApp/WEB-INF/jsp/addEmployee.jsp

Comment: Thanks for reply, posted my web.xml and pom.xml

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: @minion ,posted my Controller, please advice

Answer (score 1):

I just solve a problem about the Spring form taglib

the error is:
No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request and no ContextLoaderListener registered?

the reason is:
you can't use form taglib directly because there is no WebApplicationContext

i find some [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html) from Spring that can explain:

> Spring provides a couple of out-of-the-box solutions for JSP and JSTL
> views. Using JSP or JSTL is done using a normal view resolver defined
> in the WebApplicationContext.Furthermore, of course you need to write
> some JSPs that will actually render the view.

the solution is:
use InternalResourceViewResolver forward to the page you use form taglib